# Any idea as to why my texture is not showing up after baking in blender, exporting to glb file, and inserting into React three dev environment?

Tags: materials, export, texture-baking

The color of the baked texture shows up fine in react but the texture nodes are not showing at all. I should see a gradient in the color from the gradient texture node and bumps from the magic texture node. Upon export, I use glb, check the apply modifiers, UVs, and Normals boxes. When inserting into react, I use an npx command to change the glb into a jsx file. I have a couple other materials/textures that are showing up fine in react. This is the only material with 2 different texture nodes attached to it but I need to have both of them on the material. Any ideas?

Note: I have a few other baked textures that are currently hidden on this model that show up just fine in React. It's just this specific baked texture that I'm having an issue with.

It should look the same in react as it does blender.

blender - before bake: [image: before bake]

blender - after bake: [image: after bake]

in react: [image: in react]

Comment: I figured it out. 
1. I was using the wrong mix and needed to use mix color. 
2. had to plug the bump into the mix.
3. had to plug the mix into the principled bsdf (on the color)